# php can not access content of an array

Tags: php, arrays

It's a result from amazon order list.

partial of `var_dump($order)` gave me this:

```
["PaymentMethodDetails"]=> array(3) {
    ["FieldValue"] => array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "Standard"
    }
    ["FieldType"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(6) "string"
    }
    ["ListMemberName"]=> string(19) "PaymentMethodDetail"
}
```

`var_dump($order->PaymentMethodDetails[0])` gave me this:

`string(8) "Standard"`

but `var_dump($order->PaymentMethodDetails[1])` gave me this:

`Undefined offset: 1`

How do I access the rest of the contents there inside[PaymentMethodDetails]?

Comment: Proper spelling is highly advisable. `PaymentMethodDetails` instead of `PaymentExecutionDetail`

Comment: sorry for the error at posting question. I changed all PaymentMethodDetails. now, this is the right question. don't know how to access the rest part of the ["PaymentMethodDetails"]

Comment: Do `var_dump($order);` just before trying to access `[0]` and just before `[1]`. According to your question, both of these should have produced the `Undefined offset` error so my best guess is that `$order` is being improperly overwritten at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You have an associative array, you need to use the keys that are shown.

```
$order->PaymentMethodDetails["FieldValue"][0]
```

is `"Standard"`

```
$order->PaymentMethodDetails["FieldType"][0]
```

is `"string"`

```
$order->PaymentMethodDetails["ListMemberName"]
```

is `"PaymentMethodDetail"`

Comment: Undefined index: ListMemberName, same for FieldValue FieldType

I saw "Do not truct var_dump" some where, but I don't understand. Maybe var_dump didn't show me the whole data structure ?

Comment: I don't know why, it's clearly shown in your `var_dump` output.

Comment: maybe PaymentMethodDetail is object? just a guess

Comment: It says `=> array(3)` so it's an array.

Comment: But `$order` is apparently an object, maybe it has a magic `__get` method that returns something different from what `var_dump()` shows. What does `var_dump($order->PaymentMethodDetails)` show?

Comment: Since `$order` is an object, you should probably be calling functions from its API rather than accessing the arrays directly.

Comment: var_dump($order->PaymentMethodDetails)

array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Standard" }

var_dump($order->PaymentMethodDetails[0])

string(8) "Standard"

Comment: As you can see, that's not the same as what you posted. The API is constructing arrays on the fly when you access the property. You need to use the proper API methods.

Comment: Barmar, I think you are right. I will try to save the data to an object $order.

Comment: When I dump $order, PaymentMethodDetails is array(3). and when I dump $order->PaymentMethodDetails its array(1). that's why I don't understand.

Comment: It's because there's a magic method that makes accessing the `PaymentMethodDetails` property return something different from what's actually in the object. You're not supposed to be doing this, you're supposed to use the API.

Comment: I see, Thank you, Barmar.